# Excel VBA Store row numbers in Array and delete multiple rows at once

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I'm trying to delete all rows on my worksheet that have a unique value in `column B`.

I know this can be done with a filter or conditioned formatting, but I would like to know if the following is possible as well, since it could be useful in other situations:

I want to loop through all rows and store the row number in an `Array` if the row has a unique value in `column B`. Then delete all the rows whose number is stored in the `Array` in one single action.

The reasoning for storing the row numbers in an `Array` instead of deleting the desired rows in the loop is to reduce runtime.

My data varies in number of rows but is always in `column A:K` and it always begins on row 6.

Below is the code I've written with inspiration from the following links:
[Dynamically adding values to the array on the go](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/dynamically-populating-array-vba-variables).
[Deleting rows whose number is stored in array in one single action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716111/delete-multiple-rows-in-excel-using-vba-based-on-an-array-of-numbers) (see Tim Williams answer).

I get the error message: `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or Argument`

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim ws4 As Worksheet: Set ws4 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim GroupValue
Dim GroupTotal As Long
Dim MyArray()
Dim y As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws4.Activate

GroupValue = ws4.Range("B6").Value ' Sets the first GroupValue
CurrentRow = 6 ' Sets the starting row
y = 0
LastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To LastRow

        GroupTotal=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B6:B"&LastRow), _
            GroupValue) ' Searches for the GroupValue and finds number of matches
        If GroupTotal = 1 Then ' If GroupTotal = 1 then add the row# to the array
            ReDim Preserve MyArray(y)
            MyArray(y) = CurrentRow
            y = y + 1
        End If

        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + GroupTotal 'set the next row to work with
        GroupValue = Range("B" & CurrentRow).Value 'set next GroupValue to find

        If GroupValue = "" Then ' Checks to see if the loop can stop
            Exit For
        End If

    Next x

'***This should delete all the desired rows but instead produces the error.***
ws4.Range("B" & Join(MyArray, ",B")).EntireRow.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I've researched for hours and tried to manipulate the code with no luck.

Comment: **Where** do you get this error?

Comment: @ashleedawg 4th to last line in the code: `ws4.Range("B" & Join(MyArray, ",B")).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: This doesn[t make a lot of sense - you're saying you know of easier ways to do this but instead you've decided to spent "hours" working on a more complicated method, because `it could be useful in other situations`?  Anyway, the first  logical troubleshooting step is, find out what the values are of your variables/expressions on the line that causes the error. (Stop just before the error by inserting a line before it with the `Stop` command.

Comment: Ok, wasn't expecting that to work:  `MyArray = Array(2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15):ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Join(MyArray, ",B")).EntireRow.Delete` but it did.... now I want to know why it didn't work for you.

Comment: A couple of things first off - is `Sheet1` active when  you run the code? Your `CountIf` looks at just `Range("B6:B"...` and doesn't take the sheet into account.  You also have `If GroupValue = ""` while `GroupValue` is a `Long`, so shouldn't it be `If GroupValue = 0`?  Also  the first element of `MyArray` is _Empty_ and the second holds the value - the array will be 0 based so let `Y=0` at the start.

Comment: @ashleedawg I know it sounds a bit strange, but I'm curious to see if it could work. Furthermore i dont have any experience working with `arrays`, so instead of avoiding it all the time I challenged myself to use it in order to gain a better understanding of `arrays`.

Comment: @ashleedawg Regarding the values of my variables I get the following: `CurrentRow = 364` this makes sense as it's the first empty row. `y = 216` this also makes sense as its the exact number of rows that should be deleted. `MyArray(215) = 363` this also makes sense as its the last row that should be deleted.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thanks for the inputs - I've changed the things you listed (see the edited code). However, I get a new error message this time. The same line produces this error now: `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed`.

Comment: Not sure there.  I copied your code, had to declare `x As Long` - remember to have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and it ran fine.  Have a look at the contents of `MyArray` just before the line executes - it should have just the row numbers and I can't see how it could get anything else.  Just noticed - you could set `GroupValue` just the once if you put it below the `For x...` line - `GroupTotal` will equal 0 at that point so it will set it as row 6 to start.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Declaring `x As Long` and using `Option Explicit` didn't help. The contents of `MyArray` are indeed the row numbers that should be deleted. The `LBound` is the row number of the first row that should be deleted and the `UBound` is the row number of the last. I wondered if it could have anything to do with my data being in a table, but I get the same error if the data is not in a table. I really can't see where the problem lies.

Comment: I get an error if it's in a table - _`1004`: Delete method of Range class failed_.  You may have to use something like `ws4.ListObjects("TableName").DataBodyRange.Range(....`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I tried to run the code when data isn't in a table and it didn't work either. When i use `ws4.ListObjects("Tabel1").DataBodyRange.Range("B" & Join(MyArray, ",B")).EntireRow.Delete` it gives me the error message: `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`. Do you think maybe using `.ListRows` could work?

Comment: I think with `.ListRows` you might have to delete one row at a time.  Not sure though.  I can't figure out why it's not working when it's not in a table though.  The worksheet isn't locked is it?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I really can't figure it out either. And no the sheet is not protected. By the way, i really appreciate you taking the time to help me out!

Comment: It's start of the month - I've spent most of the morning running reports and watching a progress bar slowly move. :)  I'm running out of ideas now though, so hoping someone else has a suggestion.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook No problem - thank you again for the help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable defined as a `Range` and `Union` each row to it.
In the example below `MyArray` is the array of row numbers that should be deleted.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim MyArray() As Variant

    MyArray = Array(2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15)

    DeleteRows MyArray

End Sub

Public Sub DeleteRows(RowNumbers As Variant, Optional SheetName As String = "")

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim x As Long

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    If SheetName = "" Then
        Set wrkSht = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
    End If

    For x = LBound(RowNumbers) To UBound(RowNumbers)
        If rRange Is Nothing Then
            Set rRange = wrkSht.Rows(RowNumbers(x))
        Else
            Set rRange = Union(rRange, wrkSht.Rows(RowNumbers(x)))
        End If
    Next x

    If Not rRange Is Nothing Then rRange.Delete

    On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure DeleteColumns."
            Err.Clear
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Select

End Sub
```

**Edit**
The `Test` procedure can be replaced with any code that creates an array of row numbers.  The array is then passed to the `DeleteRows` procedure.  You could also pass it a sheet name to delete the rows from: `DeleteRows MyArray, "Sheet2"`.

The `DeleteRows` procedure sets up the variables, turns error checking on and then checks if a sheet name was passed to it.  It then sets a reference to either the active sheet or the named sheet. You could also check if the passed sheet actually exists here.

Next a loop starts going from the first to last element of the array. The first is usually 0 so you could replace `LBOUND(RowNumbers)` with `0`.

`rRange` is the variable that's going to hold the row references to delete and `Union` won't work if it doesn't already hold a range reference.
On the first pass of the loop it won't hold a reference so will be nothing and the first row in the array will be set as the first row reference on the sheet held in `wrkSht`.
On subsequent passes `rRange` will already hold a reference so the next row will be unioned to it.
Those two decisions are made in an `IF...END IF` block seperated by an `ELSE` statement.

After the loop has finished a single line `IF` statement - no `END IF` required on single line - checks if `rRange` holds any references. If it does then those rows are deleted.

The procedure exits the main body of code, deals with the error handling and then ends.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer! However, there are a lot of things that I don't understand in your code as I'm still pretty new to VBA. First off - what does your `ERROR_HANDLER` do? Regarding the bulk of the code, it would be awesome if you could explain a bit of the logic behind it? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Only just seen this comment.  Without an error handler code will just fall over whenever an error occurs.  The code I've put in there doesn't do anything at the moment - just displays whatever message an error would give, but you could deal with any expected errors - if, for example, a non-existent sheet name was passed to the procedure you'd get a `Subscript out of range` error.  You could add `Case 9: Set wrkSht = ActiveSheet:Resume Next` which will default to the Activesheet in the case of that error occuring.

Comment: Have updated my answer with an explanation of the code.